# Django Test Error When Using Custom User Model & django-allauth

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I've been creating a Django app and am trying to get the login and authentication working correctly. I have created a custom user model to override Django's default user model and am using a Postgres backend. When I try and add django-allauth to the INSTALLED_APPS and then try and run "manage.py test" I get an error.

My project structure is as follows;

```
project/
   project_app/
      settings.py
      urls.py
   accounts/
      models.py #CustomUser model defined in here
      tests.py
      views.py
      managers.py
      admin.py
```

A snippet of my settings.py is;

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    'accounts',
    
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'dj_rest_auth',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.CustomUser"
```

When I add the line `allauth.account` to my settings.py file and then run "manage.py test" I get the error `ValueError: Related model 'accounts.customuser' cannot be resolved`. Without this line added the tests run ok. Full error trace below.

```
 File "/code/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/code/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 55, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 725, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 643, in setup_databases
    return _setup_databases(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 179, in setup_databases
    connection.creation.create_test_db(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 74, in create_test_db
    call_command(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 181, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 343, in create_model
    sql, params = self.table_sql(model)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 162, in table_sql
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 215, in column_sql
    db_params = field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1004, in db_parameters
    return {"type": self.db_type(connection), "check": self.db_check(connection)}
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1001, in db_type
    return self.target_field.rel_db_type(connection=connection)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 897, in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 644, in foreign_related_fields
    return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field)
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 632, in related_fields
    return self.resolve_related_fields()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 936, in resolve_related_fields
    related_fields = super().resolve_related_fields()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 615, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'accounts.customuser' cannot be resolved
```

This only seems to happen when I try and run tests and not in the development database. I wondered if this was something to do with the order in which the test database is applying migrations, but don't know how to change that or if anyone else had come across this scenario.

Any help much appreciated as I'm running out of ideas!

Comment: try AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.models.CustomUser"

Comment: Sadly not. If I do that I get an error from the development server of `ValueError: Invalid model reference 'accounts.models.CustomUser'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName`

Comment: did you run makemigrations?

Comment: @Razenstein yes, all migrations have been run and migrated. I followed this [article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2021/07/08/what-you-should-know-about-the-django-user-model.html) in creating my custom user model. I am wondering if it's something to do with the manually created first migration for the CITextExtension. I have also tried all the steps in [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313#comment:24) and replaced all my references to get_user_model with settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

Comment: This only seems to happen when I include allauth.account within my settings.py and only fails when I try and run the unit tests. I've looked in the source code for django-allauth and it references the user model through `USER_MODEL = getattr(settings, "AUTH_USER_MODEL", "auth.User")` which looks ok

Comment: please add the full error trace to your post

Comment: Full error trace added

Comment: the error happens during migrations ... you changed a migrations file manually? better dont do that unless you really know what you are doing. Recommendation if database data is just testdata: delete database,  delete all migration files, run makemigrations, run migrate ... work with newly setup database

Comment: if you alter a migrations file after applying it to a database1 with migrate, it will not be applied to that database1again because migration state is stored in a table in database1 during migrate command. BUT it will be applied if you migrate another database2 and there might popup errors from the altered migrations file

Comment: The manually added migration was created before the first automatically generated migration was created, so that the first automatically generated migration would depend on it. Both migrations were then migrated to the database. I noticed in [here](https://adamj.eu/tech/2023/02/23/migrate-django-postgresql-ci-fields-case-insensitive-collation/) that CITextFields & CIEmailFields are being deprecated so I upgraded Django to 4.2 and replaced the code in the manual migration with a collation. I deleted all tables and rebuilt everything.
Same effect at the same point with allauth and tests

Comment: I think the issue is the order in which migrations are applied. If I try to migrate to the database from a clean set of migrations it appears to try and apply the allauth.account migration first before my CustomUser model which is 0002_initial (0001_postgres_extensions is the manually added migration)
`Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, accounts, admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions, sites, socialaccount
Running migrations:
  Applying accounts.0001_postgres_extensions... OK
  Applying account.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. It was the order that migrations are applied. In the migration that related to my custom user model I had to add a `run_before` attribute to my Migration class manually so that the django-allauth migrations would only run after the custom user model had been migrated to the test or development database.

```
run_before = [
    ('account', '0001_initial'),
]
```

Link to official docs for [Controlling the order of migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/writing-migrations/#controlling-the-order-of-migrations)

Comment: Can you please help on which file this should be added and at what place